# Icecast metadata capture

Tags: node.js, angular, stream, metadata, icecast

I've been using the package [node-icy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/icy#client) to grab metadata from an icecast stream.

What is doing is is grabbing the metadata from the stream. Then, the stream is decoded using lame and played on the Speaker.

```
   server.listen(port, ()=>{

        icy.get(url, (res)=> {
            // log HTTP responses headers
            console.error(res.headers);

            //log any "metadata" events that happen
            res.on('metadata', (metadata)=>{
                var parsed = icy.parse(metadata);
                console.log('Metadata event');
                console.error(parsed);
            });

            // Let's play the music (assuming MP3 data). 
            // lame decodes and Speaker sends to speakers! 
            res.pipe(new lame.Decoder())
                .pipe(new Speaker());
        });


        console.log(`Server on port: ${port}`);
    });
```

This will give me an output of the titles of the songs:

```
Metadata event
{ StreamTitle: 'ruby the hatchet - planetary space child - killer' }
```

If I remove

```
 res.pipe(new lame.Decoder())
            .pipe(new Speaker());
```

Then the metadata is grabbed only once. My guess is that the Speaker() function keeps running and when metadata changes, then icy.get will run res.on('metadata', ...).

I'm handling the streamer on the server and then send it to the Client on Angular 5. Is there a way to keep the `icy.get(...)` listening without using Speaker(). I'm fairly new to streams. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by using

```
var icy = require('icy');
var devnull = require('dev-null');

icy.get(url, function (res) {

    // log any "metadata" events that happen
    res.on('metadata', function (metadata) {
      const parsed = icy.parse(metadata);
      console.log('metadata', parsed);
    });

    res.pipe(devnull());
});
```

You can see it here: 
https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-icy/issues/16